# can maximum size apk file will affect performance of apps?

Tags: android

suppose My application is too big near about 55mb then is there way to reduce apk size, if maximum size apk affect performance then how i solve this issue.can anybody suggest me the answer

Thanking You

Comment: you mean runtime performance / sales performance?

Comment: yes.just i want to know when i will install my apps on powered device then how will runtime performance. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A large APK has no relationship of slow runtime performance. It depends how you manage the resources. However, a large APK does impact Sales Performance, as users prefer to download smaller apps in Google Market. Same thing applies to Apple apps.

Answer (score 0):

use `TraceView` in ur `DDMS` for Performance Testing which gives graphical view of performance traces of your application.